# (String, String) in Scala Apache Spark

Tags: string, scala, apache-spark

I have a file where each line contains `(Stringx, Stringy)`

I want to find the occurrences of `Stringy` in the entire dataset.
The code that I have managed so far is as follows:

```
val file = sc.textFile("s3n://bucket/test.txt") // RDD[ String ]
val splitRdd = file.map(line => line.split("\t"))    
    // RDD[ Array[ String ]
val yourRdd = splitRdd.flatMap(arr => {
      val title = arr(0)
      val text = arr(1)
      val words = text.split(" ")
      words.map(word => (word, title))
    })
    // RDD[ ( String, String ) ]

scala> val s = yourRdd.map(word => ((word, scala.math.log(N/(file.filter(_.split("\t")(1).contains(word.split(",")(1))).count)))))
<console>:31: error: value split is not a member of (String, String)
       val s = yourRdd.map(word => ((word, scala.math.log(N/(file.filter(_.split("\t")(1).contains(word.split(",")(1))).count)))))
```

Here `N = 20` (it is a fixed value)
How should I solve this?

**UPDATE**

Implementing Brendon's comment

```
scala> val s = yourRdd.map(word => (word, scala.math.log(N / file.filter(_.split("\t")(1).contains(word._1.split(",")(1))).count)))
s: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[((String, String), Double)] = MapPartitionsRDD[18] at map at <console>:33

scala> s.first()
15/04/23 15:43:44 INFO SparkContext: Starting job: first at <console>:36
15/04/23 15:43:44 INFO DAGScheduler: Got job 16 (first at <console>:36) with 1 output partitions (allowLocal=true)
15/04/23 15:43:44 INFO DAGScheduler: Final stage: Stage 17(first at <console>:36)
15/04/23 15:43:44 INFO DAGScheduler: Parents of final stage: List()
15/04/23 15:43:44 INFO DAGScheduler: Missing parents: List()
15/04/23 15:43:44 INFO DAGScheduler: Submitting Stage 17 (MapPartitionsRDD[18] at map at <console>:33), which has no missing parents
15/04/23 15:43:44 INFO MemoryStore: ensureFreeSpace(11480) called with curMem=234927, maxMem=277842493
15/04/23 15:43:44 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_18 stored as values in memory (estimated size 11.2 KB, free 264.7 MB)
15/04/23 15:43:44 INFO MemoryStore: ensureFreeSpace(5713) called with curMem=246407, maxMem=277842493
15/04/23 15:43:44 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_18_piece0 stored as bytes in memory (estimated size 5.6 KB, free 264.7 MB)
15/04/23 15:43:44 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_18_piece0 in memory on localhost:59043 (size: 5.6 KB, free: 264.9 MB)
15/04/23 15:43:44 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Updated info of block broadcast_18_piece0
15/04/23 15:43:44 INFO SparkContext: Created broadcast 18 from broadcast at DAGScheduler.scala:839
15/04/23 15:43:44 INFO DAGScheduler: Submitting 1 missing tasks from Stage 17 (MapPartitionsRDD[18] at map at <console>:33)
15/04/23 15:43:44 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Adding task set 17.0 with 1 tasks
15/04/23 15:43:44 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 0.0 in stage 17.0 (TID 22, localhost, PROCESS_LOCAL, 1301 bytes)
15/04/23 15:43:44 INFO Executor: Running task 0.0 in stage 17.0 (TID 22)
15/04/23 15:43:44 INFO HadoopRDD: Input split: file:/home/ec2-user/input/OUTPUT/temp:0+128629
15/04/23 15:43:44 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 17.0 (TID 22)
org.apache.spark.SparkException: RDD transformations and actions can only be invoked by the driver, not inside of other transformations; for example, rdd1.map(x => rdd2.values.count() * x) is invalid because the values transformation and count action cannot be performed inside of the rdd1.map transformation. For more information, see SPARK-5063.
```

Comment: the direct problem is that `yourRdd` is of type `(String, String)` therefore in `yourRDD.map(word => ...)` word is of type `(String, String).  Moving past that syntax error, the approach will not work as you are attempting to map over the file RDD and that's not supported.  What are you trying to attempt? This looks like TF-IDF, right?

Comment: @maasg Yes! you're right! But I want to do it without using the MLlib.

Comment: @maasg: That's awesome. How did you come to that conclusion?

Comment: "RDD transformations and actions can only be invoked by the driver" - I mentioned the approach will not work - you need to take another strategy. Consider counting all words from the text first. That gives an `RDD[Word,Count]` that you could join with the `RDD[Title, Words]`

Answer (score 0):

It is looking for the value, 'split', in word (which would be a 'def split' member). 'word', however, is not a String, it is a (String, String) and Tuples do not have a split method. I believe you meant to do `word._1.split(",")(0)`, the command becomes:

```
val s = yourRdd.map(word => (word, scala.math.log(N / file.filter(_.split("\t")(1).contains(word._1.split(",")(1))).count)))
```

Edit::

With the clarity provided by maasg's answer to the real underlying question, I see that I needed to count the unique instances of a word per title. I would up-vote maasg's answer but I don't have enough rep yet :(

```
val sc = SparkApplicationContext.coreCtx
val N = 20
var rdd: RDD[String] = sc.parallelize(Seq("t1\thi how how you,you", "t1\tcat dog,cat,mouse how you,you"))
val splitRdd: RDD[Array[String]] = rdd.map(line => line.split("\t"))

//Uniqe words per title and then reduced by title into a count
val wordCountRdd = splitRdd.flatMap(arr =>
  arr(1).split(" |,").distinct //Including a comma cause you seem to split on this later on to, but I don't think you actually need too
    .map(word => (word, 1))
).reduceByKey{case (cumm, one) => cumm + one}

val s: RDD[(String, Double)] = wordCountRdd.map{ case (word, freq) => (word, scala.math.log(N / freq)) }
s.collect().map(x => println(x._1 + ", " + x._2))
```

Comment: Using word(0) parametersizes it. But String, String does not take parameters.

Comment: This will not work.  File is an RDD and RDDs cannot be used in closures as serialization is not defined for an RDD.

Comment: Your code is correct but there seems to be an issue with my file.filter(..) code. As it runs into an infinite loop it seems. I am trying to count the number of lines in the file that contain the word. Can you help me out on this ?

Comment: Updated my post. Please see above.

Comment: Sorry, I naively assumed that the question was regarding the error. Will update.

Comment: @AngryPanda updated as promised. Sorry for the late response, had to go to lunch. Hope this is what your are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, it's not possible to use an RDD "nested"  within the closure operating on another RDD. This calls for a change in strategy.
Making the assumption that each title is unique, and trying to work in the same lines as in the original question, this could be an alternative to eliminate the need for the nested RDD computation:

```
val file = sc.textFile("s3n://bucket/test.txt") // RDD[ String ]
val wordByTitle = file.flatMap{line => 
    val split = line.split("\t")
    val title = split(0)
    val words = split(1).split(" ")
    words.map(w=> (w,title))
}

// we want the count of documents in which a word appears, 
// this is equivalent to counting distinct (word, title) combinations.
// note that replacing the title by a hash would save considerable memory
val uniqueWordPerTitle = wordByTitle.distinct()

// now we can calculate the word frequency acros documents
val tdf = uniqueWordPerTitle.map{case (w, title) => (w,1)}.reduceByKey(_ + _)

// and the inverse document frequency per word.
val idf = tdf.map{case (word,freq) => (word, scala.math.log(N/freq))}
```